# Numfmt --to=none inside a function

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-interface, gnu

I want to create a new number column in a non-human-readable format in a csv using sed. To do so, I'll create a function and then apply it in sed via `sed 's/(.*)/foo \1/e`. Now, I've tested `cat $file | cut -f1 -d" " | numfmt --from=iec --to=none` directly on the file, and it returns exactly what I'm looking for. When I try to put it in a function:

`foo(){cat $1 | cut -f1 -d" " | numfmt --from=iec --to=none}`

numfmt gets very unhappy and insists that `none}` is an invalid format; when I add a space in between the "none" and the curly brace, numfmt sits patiently waiting for input, instead of closing out the function definition.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `shellcheck` would help you with that and other things if you ran it as instructed in the info for the [tag:bash] tag you used - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the tip, with that I was able to create the following which I was able to define: `foo(){ numfmt --from=iec --to=none < "$1"; }` with the semicolon being the key. I've written many functions and never needed the semicolon; why is that necessary here?

Comment: You always need a semicolon or newline before the `}` at the end of a function or any other block of code wrapped in `{ ... }`.

Comment: Ah it's the newline, right..... I rarely define functions in-line like this, so it didn't occur to me that the newline represents the semicolon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space after `{` and a `;` before `}`:

```
foo(){ cat $1 | cut -f1 -d" " | numfmt --from=iec --to=none; }
```

Cleaning up a bit more:

```
foo(){ cut -f1 -d' ' "$1" | numfmt --from=iec --to=none; }
```

or:

```
foo(){ numfmt --from=iec --to=none < <(cut -f1 -d' ' "$1"); }
```